# How to maintain theme color using checkbox even when page reloads?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a checkbox which activates a change of theme from dark/light. Light is the default theme.

```
<div class="switch">
    <label>
        <input id="layoutSwitch" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
$('#layoutSwitch').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#bodyLayout').addClass("bodyLayout"); 
        $('#leftMenu').addClass("leftMenu");
    }else{
        $('#bodyLayout').removeClass("bodyLayout");  
        $('#leftMenu').removeClass("leftMenu");  
    }
});
```

My dark theme css:

```
/* Dark Theme */
.bodyLayout {
    background-color: #525a69; }
       .leftMenu {
          background-color: #252d3a; }\
```

What I want is to maintain the same selected theme even when I reload the page. And also maintain the current selection of the checkbox even when page reloads.

I found this code while searching. It works when I use it alone but when I try to join it with the code above, it doesn't function right and also it selects all the switches on my page. I want only the selected switch alone.

```
$(function(){
var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
$('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/jn1we569/6/

```js
$('#layoutSwitch').change(function() {
  $('#bodyLayout').toggleClass("bodyLayout"); 
  $('#leftMenu').toggleClass("leftMenu");
  localStorage.setItem('layoutSwitch', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

localStorage.layoutSwitch === 'true'? $('#layoutSwitch').prop('checked', true).trigger("change"): '';
```

```css
.bodyLayout {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #525a69; 
}

.leftMenu {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #252d3a; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">
    <label>
        <input id="layoutSwitch" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="bodyLayout"></div>
<div id="leftMenu"></div>
```

In stackoverflow it's not working because of localStorage, please check the jsfiddle.

First you need to have the `change event`, then your `localStorage` statement to check for `checkbox` checked.

Instead of checking for `checkbox`, use `jQuery` `toggleClass` method for toggling the classes.

Your entire `JavaScript` code will go inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(function(){
> var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
> $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
> });
>
> $('input').on('change', function() {
> localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
> console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
> });
> ```

What you are doing with this code is saving the state of input into local storage.

The mistake here is you are triggering this on all input tags on the page using `$('input')`. If you want to save only `$('#layoutSwitch')` checkbox, pass this instead of `$('input')`.

So following code should work:

```
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('#layoutSwitch').prop('checked', test || false);
    updateTheme();
});

$('#layoutSwitch').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));    // remove this line if you do not want to log value in console
    updateTheme();
});

function updateTheme()
    if($('#layoutSwitch').is(":checked")){
        $('#bodyLayout').addClass("bodyLayout"); 
        $('#leftMenu').addClass("leftMenu");
    }else{
        $('#bodyLayout').removeClass("bodyLayout");  
        $('#leftMenu').removeClass("leftMenu");  
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. the switch is alright because it doesn't revert to previous selection when page reloads but the theme still changes back to default every time I reload the page.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `updateTheme()` in first function after setting checked property of checkbox and it is not being changed in your further operations.

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector to ID, such as input1,input2

```
    $(function(){

    for (var selectorId in localStorage){
       if(selectorId.contains("input")){
          var test = localStorage.getItem(selectorId) === 'true'? true: false;

          $('#'selectorId).prop('checked', test || false);
      }
    }


    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var selectorId = $(this).attr("id");
        localStorage[selectorId] = $(this).is(':checked');
        console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    });


});
```

Comment: Can you give a complete answer together with the code for the theme above. The switch works perfectly fine but the code for changing theme still reverts back to its default theme.